# Getting Errors with enumitem !Undefined Control Sequence<argument> \scriptsize \SetEnumitemSize{script}\scriptsize

Tags: enumitem, mac

I am trying to compile this code:

```
\documentclass[fourbysix]{recipecard}
\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}% load the package without redefining the original lists
\newlist{instructions}{enumerate}{1}% create a new enumerated list with depth 1
\setlist[instructions,1]{label=\arabic*.~}% define a label for level 1
\begin{document}
\ingredient{plums}
\ingredient{ 4 cups sugar}
\changeingrdlistnum{3}
\begin{recipe}{Plum Cordial}{~ one litre}
\begin{instructions}
         \item Instruction one. 
         \item Instruction two.
\end{instructions}
\cookingtime{20 minutes}
\cooktemp{0}
 
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

But all I am getting are these Undefined Control Sequence Errors that all concern themselves with font size. How can I fix this when enumitem.sty is an included file within Texlive? I am attempting to enumerate the instructions within a recipecard. I have found this sample code, and then when I try to run the solution the errors happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size commands are not defined by LaTeX but by the document class you are using, and this one only defines `\normalsize`

`enumitem` assumes a standard set so as a quick fix you can define them all to be `\normalsize`

```
\let\textdegree\undefined
\documentclass[fourbysix]{recipecard}

\let\tiny\normalsize
\let\scriptsize\normalsize
\let\footnotesize\normalsize
\let\small\normalsize
\let\large\normalsize
\let\Large\normalsize
\let\LARGE\normalsize
\let\huge\normalsize
\let\Huge\normalsize

\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}% load the package without redefining the original lists
\newlist{instructions}{enumerate}{1}% create a new enumerated list with depth 1
\setlist[instructions,1]{label=\arabic*.~}% define a label for level 1
\begin{document}
\ingredient{plums}
\ingredient{ 4 cups sugar}
\changeingrdlistnum{3}
\begin{recipe}{Plum Cordial}{~ one litre}
\begin{instructions}
         \item Instruction one. 
         \item Instruction two.
\end{instructions}
\cookingtime{20 minutes}
\cooktemp{0}
 
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!